# Bottom navigation bar overlapping viewpager in CoordinatorLayout Android

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-bottom-nav-view

I have a recycler view in viewpager but the last row of recycler view is not fully visible (ie partially visible) as the Bottom navigation view is overlapping the viewpager. How can I fix this issue?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.booksummary.booksummaryvideos.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    <!--android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the `BottomNavigationView`is in fact overlapping your`ViewPager`...

You can either change your layout so that the `ViewPager` ends above the `BottomNavigationView`

or

You need to set bottom padding to the size of the `BottomNavigationView` on the `RecyclerView` and also (to ensure the padding is after the last item) `clipToPadding="false"`